# SQL query to JOIN two tables with no relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble getting the records on the Monthly average Cost per Item with this table values.
[image]

[image]

I need a result like this:

[image]

What I want to get is all the month from January to December even if there is no transaction on that month of that item.

Is this possible ?

Comment: You don't need to join table 1 at all, just convert the date to a month name as per suggestion by @NonProgrammer. This is much simpler

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yes but it will not show the other months if it has no transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (assuming T-SQL):

```
select b.ItemName, a.MonthName, round(coalesce(avg(c.Cost), 0)) as avg_cost
from table_1 a
join (select ItemName from table_2 group by ItemName) b
on 1 = 1
left join table_2 c
on month(c.TransactionDate) = a.MonthID
and b.ItemName = c.ItemName
group by b.ItemName, a.MonthName
order by b.ItemName, a.MonthID;
```

Comment: I run your query, it works but it don't give the exact average. I don't know why but it averages all the transaction on every month (item_1 and item_2)

Comment: @princevezt I added the join clause

Answer (score 1):

I am away from my computer, but I would do the following in terms of concept:

1. Generate a table/temp table that uses a min and max dates from your transaction date field.  This table has at least three columns: 1. Month name 2. Start date (along with year if doing this multiple years) for that month 3. End date in same manners as start date. 
   URL to use for Step 1: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/
2. Join on the table from step 1 where transaction date between start date and end date
3. Finally, group / avg it.

Hope this helps.  Tomorrow, if you still need help with this, I'll post the query.

Comment: I think easier way to go about it would be replacing transaction date to month name using following query:   select datename(Transactiondate)

Comment: how can i join the table ? there is no key or relationship. @_@

Comment: If you are talking about step 1, you can do following to join:  select * from table1 join table2 on (table1.Transactiondate >= StartDate) AND (tabel1.TransactionDate <= EndDate). Keep in mind, there are multiple ways to join two tables.  You don't necessarily have to join on ID = ID.

Comment: sorry for being novice, can you show me how to do this ? I'm interested on your solution.

Comment: the answer of @Mackers works, but i still want to see your solution. for learning purposes. thank you.